# Changing text depending selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added an element per JavaScript with a text. With this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ($('welcome_page').length) {
   $('#my_element').after('<tr><td><td><td id="welcome_message">Welcome to my page</td></td></td</tr>');
   }
});
```

I need to able to change the text >Welcome to my page< depending on the language set in the page:

```
<select id="languages" onchange="submit();">
<option value="1" selected="">English</option>
<option value="2">Spanish</option>
<option value="3">French</option>
</select>
```

I've tried this but it does not do the trick:

```
function langChoice(sel){
    var langChange = document.getElementById('languages');
    var langOption = document.getElementById('welcome_message');
        if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "1" ) {
        langOption.innerHTML = "Enter price per month";
        }
        else if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "2" ) {
        langOption.innerHTML = "Enter price per week";
        }
        else if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "3" ) {
        langOption.innerHTML = "Enter price per day";
        }
        else if ( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value == "4" ) {
        langOption.innerHTML = "Enter for sale hour";
        }

}
```

Comment: Where you call your function??

Comment: Could you add a plunker and replicate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess...

visit this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L93qwey4/)

HTML:

```
<div id="greet"></div>
<select id="languages">
    <option value="en" >English</option>
    <option value="es" selected>Spanish</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var welcome = {
    en:"English",
    es:"Espanol",
    fr:"Francais"
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#greet').html(welcome[$('#languages').val()]);
});

$('#languages').change(function () {
    $('#greet').html(welcome[$('#languages').val()]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ($('welcome_page').length) {
   $('#my_element').after('<tr><td><td><td id="welcome_message">Welcome to my page</td></td></td</tr>');

   langChoice($("#languages"))

   }
});
```

i suppose that drop down menu #languages is present in the page; i not undestand $("welcome_page")..  perhaps $("#welcome_page") or you use a tag  ??

Answer (score 0):

OK then do one thing call the function langChoice(sel) inside the first line of your submit() function

**For example :-**

```
function submit() {
  langChoice($("#languages"));

  .. your logic ..
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. That's why I'm using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If I understood Correctly:

```
<div id="welcome_page">
    <select id="languages" onchange="submit();">
        <option value="1" selected="">English</option>
        <option value="2">Spanish</option>
        <option value="3">French</option>
    </select>
    <div id="my_element"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#welcome_page').length) {
       $('#my_element').after('<tr><td><td><td id="welcome_message">Welcome to my page</td></td></td</tr>');
    }

$("#languages").on("change",function(){
    var Val = $(this).val();

    if(Val==1){
        $("#welcome_message").html("English");
    }
    else if(Val==2){
        $("#welcome_message").html("Spanish");
    }
    else if(Val==3){
        $("#welcome_message").html("French");
    }

});


});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tufce1yo/

Comment: It's almost right. But the new text should appear direclty (if it's English it should show English from the beginning not the original text)

Comment: You set the initial text to English - call it your starting language, then the user changes it to whatever language he wants like it works above, if you want to remember the users selection when changing pages I once did it by setting a session for each language in PHP (with ajax) when you change the select value that way it remembers it.

Comment: can you update the code so that it shows the changed text directly? At times the page will open in French so the initial text should not appear at all

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you want to achieve: The user enters your website which is initially in English lets say, then he chooses french which will change the whole websites language to French for all pages, is that correct?

Comment: not really. The page will open in the browser language (or the language is set by URL parameter). So if your browser is in French, the page will open with the value "Frech" already selected in language dropdown menu

Comment: ok, its not rally relevant what the starting language is. The question is what do you want to achieve next?

Comment: actually I don't need the original text at all. I just entered it to create the element. What I really need is the changed texts per language

Comment: You want the websites entire lang changed based on user selection?

Comment: I want that the text of the element "welcome_message" appears according to the selected language in the dropdown menu (whether it appears by opening the page for the first time or by changeing it manually in the drop down doesnt matter)

Comment: In my code I showed you how its done when changing the selection, But if the user closes the browser there is no way for it to start from the language he selected it will start from the language you specified as the starting language unless you put this variable into a database next to the user id and if hes logged in it will start from that language

Comment: the code should check first what language value is selected and then pick the respective text (no standard landing text)

Comment: So just add the if statement inside the on-change function at the very top of the code so it first checks and sets the language and then does the same thing again onchange

Comment: could you please update the Fiddle to see how you do it?

Comment: the selected language is kept to the next page per session. If I add another text in the next page that should also appear according to the previously selected language how can I retrieve the language value from the session?

Comment: at the beginning of every page you check the session with php and echo the appropriate language or pass the session the a js variable and echo the text from javascript as you prefer